# load link src into iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, src

I was wondering if it's possible to have jQuery look at a group of links within a div class, and when one of those links are clicked the src of that link will load in the iframe.

I think it would be something like

```
$(function() {
$('.link_group a').on('click', function(){
   $('iframe#frameID').attr('src', $(this).attr);
});
});
```

EDIT- my jQuery now looks like this

```
$(function() {
$('.link_group a').on('click', function(){
$('iframe#frameID').attr('src', $(this).prop('href'));
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="link_group">
<a href="Link 1.asp">Link 1</a>
<a href="Link 2.asp">Link 2</a>
<a href="Link 3.asp">Link 3</a>
<a href="Link 4.asp">Link 4</a>
</div>
```

but thats definitely not working..

Would anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a parameter to the `attr()` method, and also select which attribute:

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

Or, more recently in jQuery:

```
$(this).prop('href');
```

Also, an `id` is unique within the document, so unless you use exactly the same script in other pages and use that `id` on other element types, specifying the `iframe` is redundant, and potentially slows down your selector.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried `$('iframe#frameID').attr('src', $(this).prop('href'));` within my function and couldn't get it to work either.. I also tried remove #frameID like you suggested, but still had no luck..

Comment: on top of using prop() i also needed to preventDefault. now evenrything works perfectly. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(this).attr("href")
```

or preferably in jQuery 1.6+:

```
$(this).prop("href")
```

instead of:

```
$(this).attr
```

Comment: ... or preferably `.prop()` since jQuery 1.6.